# Does anyone know a way to get such an End Arrow type in Visio?

Tags: microsoft-visio, shapes

Does anyone know a way to get such an End Arrow type in Visio?

```
------------
|   App    |
------------
     |
     |
     |
     | Λ
     |_|
------------
|  Server  |
------------
```

Image for more clarity:

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the steps in the screen recording below：

[image]

The main step is to right-click the drawn connector and select format shape.

Comment: Won't this sort of design will break if you move the shapes? The connector is supposed to follow the shape it's connected to. Isn't "custom line ends" a better option? You can check more about that here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-a-new-fill-pattern-line-pattern-or-line-ends-pattern-bc636108-1fe1-4a24-8ec5-6b7de8b16dca